# In MATLAB, how to generate a complex positive definite matrix whose diagonal elements belong to the interval (0,1]?

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, linear-algebra, algebra

I am currently using the following code to generate a real positive definite matrix of size n.

```
A = (mvnrnd(zeros(n,1), eye(n), n))';
```

How do I generate for complex entries with the same constraint that all the diagonal elements are between (0,1]?

Comment: add to it `B = i*(mvnrnd(zeros(n,1),zeros(n), n)).';` Note the transpose: `.'`  as opposed to the default conjugate transpose `'`

Comment: You mean i*(mvnrnd(zeros(n,1),eye(n), n)).'? But this does not guarantee the constraint.

Comment: I wasnt sure about the constraint, just noticed your diagonal should be real (I think) according to your post.

Comment: Do you want random elements in (0,1] on your diagonal?

Comment: NOTE : diagonal elements in your matrix can be set/accessed using linear indexing - If n=size(A,1), then : 
A(1:(n+1):end) are exactly your diagonal terms

Comment: By the way are you sure you're generating only positive definite matrices with your code?

Comment: `>> n = 4

n =

     4

>> A = (mvnrnd(zeros(n,1), eye(n), n))';
>> A

A =

    0.5377    1.8339   -2.2588    0.8622
    0.3188   -1.3077   -0.4336    0.3426
    3.5784    2.7694   -1.3499    3.0349
    0.7254   -0.0631    0.7147   -0.2050`
I just tried this. So you can see It;s not positive

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam : What do you mean by positive definite matrix?

Comment: [~,p] = chol(A) indicates that A is not positive definite matrix (because p > 0). alternatively look at the eigenvalues of A.

Comment: ahh sorry that's my mistake. reading in English `positive definite matrix` makes me translate it literally. And I thought it's simple matrix with positive numbers lol... now I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried something and get this:

```
A = (mvnrnd(zeros(n,1), eye(n), n))'
A = A+A'
A = A + 4*n*eye(n)
C = rand(n)
C=C-C'
D = A+i*C
chol(D)
```

Using your distribution parameters generate random `A` matrix. Make this symmetric, add elements at main diagonal, create complex part, sum them. This describes a 4sigma probability interval of getting positive define matrix. 
But my method has one weak point - it based on symmetric and skew-simmetric matrices. Is it ok for you?